# Несколько разрешений Android

Tags: android, permissions, android-permissions, runtime-permission

В Activity запрашивается несколько разрешений.

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(
    int requestCode,
    @NonNull String[] permissions,
    @NonNull int[] grantResults
) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_CAMERA:
            if (PermissionUtil.isCameraPermissionGranted(permissions, grantResults) || PermissionUtil.isCameraPermissionGranted(requireContext())) {
        ...
    }
}
```

И хочется понять, есть ли какой-либо смысл в такой двойной проверке одного и того же разрешения (на камеру), если эти методы выглядят так:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
fun isCameraPermissionGranted(
    permissions: Array<String>,
    grantResults: IntArray
): Boolean {
    if (permissions.isEmpty()) {
        return false
    }
    val size = permissions.size
    for (i in 0 until size) {
        if (permission == permissions[i]) {
            return grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

и

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
fun isCameraPermissionGranted(context: Context): Boolean {
    if (permissions.isEmpty()) {
        return true
    }
    return permissions.none { ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, it) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED }
}
```

Вроде как первый метод без второго не всегда может работать - например, этот метод будет true только в случаях, если пользователь только что принял разрешение, а если это разрешение было принято ранее, вернёт true второй метод. Но второй метод вернёт true и в случае, если пользователь только что принял разрешение. Т.е. первый без второго был недостаточен. И мой вопрос в том, излишен ли первый метод? Т.е. есть ли разница, использовать один второй метод без первого или использовать эту конструкцию из двух методов?